# Unable to override compare() method of Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I’m not sure why I get this below error though I already implemented the method.

“The method compare(Student, Student) of type NameComparator must override or implement a supertype method” in NameComparator.java while implementing the compare method

### Student.java

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String lesson;
    private int grade;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, int age, String lesson, int grade) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.lesson = lesson;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getLesson() {
        return lesson;
    }

    public void setLesson(String lesson) {
        this.lesson = lesson;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[name=" + this.name + ", age=" + this.age + ", lesson="
                + this.lesson + ", grade=" + this.grade + "]";
    }

}
```

### NameComparator.java

```
import java.util.Comparator;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class NameComparator implements Comparator {

// I’m getting this error for below method "The method compare(Student, Student) of type NameComparator must override or implement a super type method"

    @Override
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        String name1 = o1.getName();
        String name2 = o2.getName();

        // ascending order (descending order would be: name2.compareTo(name1))
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }

}
```

Comment: change `implements` part  to `implements Comparator<Student>`

Comment: What do you think `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`? Why did you add it?

Comment: When the Comparator is not parameterized I get this warning “Comparator is a raw type. References to generic type Comparator<T> should be parameterized” for implementing the Comparator interface . So inorder to suppress this warning added that. May be this is a kind of Dumb programing :) #Boris the Spider

Comment: Well, that is exactly what caused your error, no? Had you read what the error meant you would have found that your `Comparator` required a generic type to function as you want it to. The lesson to learn here is to read and fully understand compiler warnings instead of ignoring them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator {
```

to

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
```

When you implement the raw `Comparator` interface (which is not advised), your `compare` method expects `Object` arguments.

Answer (score 4):

The [`Comparator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface is a *generic* interface. As is, it took the default implementation of `Comparator<Object>`, which would mean that it is expecting `public int compare(Object s1, Object s2) {` to be implemented.

To fix this, simply replace `Comparator` with `Comparator<Student>` in you class decleration.

Comment: Is this what people say "Java generic is *invariant*", which means if the code doesn't explicitly use `<T>` notation, then `Object` methods are always called (`Any?` in Kotlin)?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa, yeah pretty much. If `<T>` is expected, but nothing is provided, then `<Object>` is used.

Answer (score 2):

The method declaration must looks like:

```
@Override
public int compare(Object s1, Object s2) {
```

Because you ot add the generic type at the `implements` clause.

Change the class declaration to:

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
```

And the error will gone.